# Android - Application Launchs the Main Activity always

Tags: android, android-homebutton

We have an issue with android application. We created a Sample project which has 3 screens. LoginScreen, WelcomeScreen,HomeScreen. 
When user login, will navigate to Welcome Screen and from Welcome screen place a button to navigate to Home Screen.

Application works fine as expected. We are facing an issue with the Device's Home Button. When user clicks on Home button the application quits and device home screen will appear to the user, and when the user opens the application again, the application should open the page, from where the user quits.

If the user quit from WelcomeScreen, welcome screen should be launched when the user open the app again, if its HomeScreen, then HomeScreen should be launched. When the connect the device in my laptop and try running directly application working fine as expected, but Issue is with copy paste the apk file.

If i copy the apk and paste that in my Device storage and run the application, its always opening the LoginScreen when the user quits from welcomeScreen or HomeScreen and click on the App icon again. Can you please help me to resolve this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to uninstall the application from your device delete all apk from the devices and then you should build directly into your device so that you can get the latest version of app installed in your device.Do this I hope that it will work.

Comment: Hi,I have uninstalled the application before copy-paste the apk in my device. But still the issue exist.

Comment: try build the application , not to copy paste the apk

Comment: Hi,Issue with copy paste the apk. When i try run directly from eclipse to device, it works fine as expected. Issue is only when i copy paste the aPK

Comment: that is what I was saying.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the support and help. I would like to resolve the issue when copy paste the apk. Why android is behaving differently when user copy paste the APK in device storage?

Comment: its not the android behaving it. Its your fault I guess. When ever you make changes in project and then you Run it on emulator or device,  IDE saves new changes in APK at compiling time of project. So before compiling time, if you would copy and past the APK in device thinking as a new APK after changes, it would not show any changes because the real changes is not yet saved in the device

Comment: so it is a good practice to run project on device directly rather then copy and paste it